# Fabric.js intersectsWithObject returning false when Object is in a group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've been trying to check if a fabric.js object is intersecting with any object of a fabric.js group. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, `intersectsWithObject` will return false.

Here is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    canvas.item(5).item(i).setCoords();
    modifiedObj.setCoords();

    if(modifiedObj.intersectsWithObject(canvas.item(5).item(i))) {
        groupBoolean = true;
    }
}
```

This is how I am creating my group:

```
var camera = new fabric.Rect({
    top : 105,
    left : 322,
    width : 52,
    height : 28,
    fill : modelStrokeColor,
    strokeWidth : modelStrokeWidth,
    stroke: modelStrokeColor
});

additionalObjects = new fabric.Group([powerButton, volumeRockers, speakers, camera]);
```

I double checked and `canvas.item(5).item(i)` definitely returns fabric rectangles.

I came across this post: [Fabricjs intersectsWithObject returning false when Object is fabric.Rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888617/fabricjs-intersectswithobject-returning-false-when-object-is-fabric-rect)

However, setting the coordinates again won't fix the problem.

Can someone help?
Thanks already!